# How to identify audio files containing same set of words?

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition

I want to implement an application where given an audio containing a speech as query,it returns the most similar audio that was already submitted by an other user.

Here two audio are similar if they contains approximately the same set of words.

For example if the query speech is "Hello World!":

- it returns "Hello my World!", "Hello Worlds!"
- it doesn't necessary returns "Hello Earth" or "Bye world!"
- it doesn't return "Trump is a dickhead" (even if it is true, but this an other story :) )

Notice that this "audio detector" MUST be robust against different timbers (different users voices). It would be cool if it is robust against noise (like reasonable outdoor noise) and melody distortion (like matching "Hello World!" with "Hellooo World!").

Comment: What you're looking for is a speech recognition system. Such a system would give you the transcription of an audio file. Try out a couple of such systems and see if you're ok with their accuracy (given the noise level you want to tolerate)

Comment: Do you plan it only for English? As mentioned above, you should start with speech recognition part, as it is the most complicated. Recognized queries can be stored in the text format in your data base (maybe with several potential transcriptions and spellings/synonyms appended). Then you do count-based or TF-IDF based ranking.

Comment: @Mido can you suggest some?

Comment: @agorin Yes, just english for now!

Comment: @justHelloWorld I'd suggest you do a quick Google search, there are a lot of options but I haven't tried any. However, if you want to customize it to your acoustic environment, I'd suggest you look for "Microsoft Custom Recognition Intelligent Service".

Comment: @justHelloWorld: you could also look towards building your own system. In this way you can customize vocabulary, language model and eventually come up with better performance.  However, it will require some work. Check CMU Sphinx to start with